# List sudo users in centos

Tags: centos5, users, sudo

How do I list all sudo users at CentOS server?

There are many groups(root, wheel, adm etc) at server, and have users in it. I am looking an easy way/command to find users in all groups who have sudo access.

Note: My user also have sudo access. And I am using 64-bit CentOS release 5.2 (Final).

Comment: Why down vote? Is there anything wrong with question?

Comment: What have you tried and why didn't it work?  It's probably worth noting that "sudo users" isn't all that accurate as the `/etc/sudoers` file can allow certain users or groups to run specific commands as root or some other user but not all commands as all users.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
for USER in `cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd`
do
  sudo -U $USER -l
done
```

Comment: Error: `sudo: illegal option `-U'`

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't try this on CentOS, only on Ubuntu.  What version of CentOS are you using?

Comment: 64-bit CentOS release 5.2 (Final). All commands I found over internet are for Ubuntu or other. Those are not working on my CentOS server.

Comment: It's not a Debian/Ubuntu specific addition.  [It's in the source](http://www.sudo.ws/sudo.man.html).  You may have better luck with a more recent version of CentOS.

Comment: No way on CentOS 5.2 ?

Comment: @Ahsan You haven't applied updates to your system in FOUR YEARS. It should read CentOS 5.9 today. Go fix that problem :)

Comment: @MichaelHampton I am not in a state to update the System :(

Answer (score 2):

What is wrong with `sudo cat /etc/sudoers` and maybe `getent group <groupname>` to get usernames of group members?

Comment: `sudo cat /etc/sudoers` shows the groups, i didnt find any users in it and also tried your commnad. I am looking easy way/command which list all users who have sudo rights?

Answer (score 1):

When adding users with sudo permissions on `centos7`, its advised to add them to the `wheel` usergroup which by default has sudo permissions with

```
sudo gpasswd -a <user_name> wheel
```

Following [@Sven](https://serverfault.com/users/8897/sven) 's answer, does the trick for `centos7`.

```
getent group wheel
```

Comment: That may be a good idea, but doesn't answer the question.